# Is there a Windows equivalent to the OSX setting for underscan on an external display?

Tags: windows-7, windows, external-display, display-settings

In OSX when using an external monitor I have the option to set the underscan in the display settings GUI:
[image: Example]

Is there a Windows equivalent to do the same? I am using Windows 7 on a Lenovo ThinkPad.

(I am also open to using 3rd party tools. I attempted to use [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) without much success)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No.

Windows does not natively expose control of under/overscan for connected displays.

Some graphics cards' software will enable the user to modify these settings, but whether that's available to you depends on the specific configuration of your system.